# Fibonacci series not working in python, Interpreter crashes

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make Fibonacci series and I'll explain what it is, You take last two numbers of a list, add them and do this again and again. That is called the Fibonacci series. But for some reason this code crashes the Interpreter or does not give any input at all, I'm using python 3
I have also tried using online Interpreters but they do not give input too, The Interpreter does not give any error, It just crashes or doesn't give input.

```
list = [1,2]
length = len(list)
while length <= 100:
    num1 = list[-1]
    num2 = list[-2]
    list.append(num1 + num2)

print(list)
```

I have also tried this but this also doesn't work

```
list = [1,2]
length = len(list)
while length != 100:
    num1 = list[-1]
    num2 = list[-2]
    list.append(num1 + num2)

print(list)
```

Comment: Calculate the `length` *inside* the loop as well.

Comment: `length` never changes from its initial 2, so the loop runs for ever. Either move `length = len(list)` inside the loop, or dispense with the separate variable entirely and check `while len(list) != 100`

Answer (score 2):

This loop:

```
while length <= 100:
    num1 = list[-1]
    num2 = list[-2]
    list.append(num1 + num2)
```

will run forever because `length <= 100` condition will always be
satisfied. To make it work as you want you have to update value of
`length` after performing the operations inside the loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

list = [1, 2]
length = len(list)
while length <= 100:
    num1 = list[-1]
    num2 = list[-2]
    list.append(num1 + num2)
    length = len(list)

print(list)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049, 12586269025, 20365011074, 32951280099, 53316291173, 86267571272, 139583862445, 225851433717, 365435296162, 591286729879, 956722026041, 1548008755920, 2504730781961, 4052739537881, 6557470319842, 10610209857723, 17167680177565, 27777890035288, 44945570212853, 72723460248141, 117669030460994, 190392490709135, 308061521170129, 498454011879264, 806515533049393, 1304969544928657, 2111485077978050, 3416454622906707, 5527939700884757, 8944394323791464, 14472334024676221, 23416728348467685, 37889062373143906, 61305790721611591, 99194853094755497, 160500643816367088, 259695496911122585, 420196140727489673, 679891637638612258, 1100087778366101931, 1779979416004714189, 2880067194370816120, 4660046610375530309, 7540113804746346429, 12200160415121876738, 19740274219868223167, 31940434634990099905, 51680708854858323072, 83621143489848422977, 135301852344706746049, 218922995834555169026, 354224848179261915075, 573147844013817084101, 927372692193078999176]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = [1,2]
length = 2                          
while length != 100:
    num1 = list[-1]
    num2 = list[-2]
    list.append(num1 + num2)
    length += 1                           # increase length to control block

print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use len() on the list directly in the while condition instead of an intermediate variable that you would need to calculate on every iteration anyway (which is what you are missing in your loop):

```
fibo = [1,2]
while len(fibo)<100:
     fibo.append(fibo[-1]+fibo[-2])
```

or you can use a list comprehension:

```
fibo = [a.append(sum(a)) or a.pop(0) for a in [[1,2]] for _ in range(100)]

print(fibo)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ... ]
```

*Note that the modern fibonacci sequence actually starts at [0,1] and the antique version starts at [1,1]*